# How can I add field information to an standard image?

Tags: views, entities

How can I automate this. I am having some sort op coupon like website. But I want the coupon code to be placed into an image. With the nessecary information from the rest of the fields, like date and other conditions, company name, etc.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? `<p>` over `<img>`? Text as a graphic? fields into EXIF?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you already have image installed and a content type set up that you have an image field attached to.

1. You will need to install the following modules [image cache actions](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) and [token](http://drupal.org/project/token)
    also the following will need to be enabled "Image Effects Text" (this is part of image cahce actions)
2. Add an image style by going to example.com/admin/config/media/image-styles and clicking add style.
3. Using the select list under Effect select text and then click add
4. You will now be in a page where you can set all the txt setting including the actual text to overlay the image with. You can select the type of text using the select list labelled "text source" if you have token installed you can select token and browse tokens for your replacement text.